# Biotic Jump and Evades Unavailable

Tags: mass-effect-andromeda

I started the game as a Vanguard, and now have Vanguard 2 and Adept 2 unlocked. Both supposedly provide the Biotic Jump and Evades power, but they're grayed out, and my character still uses the jump jets. Switching profiles does not enable it. I haven't seen anything mentioning unlocking this skill separately from the profile. What do I need to do to get my biotic jumps?

Comment: Have you activated those profiles by any chance?

Comment: Assuming activated means equipped, then yes. I have all the other benefits of the profile available. Only the one is deactivated.

Comment: So your current equipped profile is vanguard or adept right, and you are still using a jet pack when leaping?

Comment: Correct. Xbox One version.

Comment: definitely a bug then, I just tried both profiles and I was using biotics

Answer (score 1):

When you go to choose a profile, on the right hand screen, you will see the description of the profile.

Scroll to the bottom, you will see that the biotic jump and evade replaces the jump-jet/evade.

As to whether it's working or not for you, it may be a glitch or a bug. (Unfortunately this game has many of those)

Comment: Yeah, the skill is there - it's just grayed out. Seems like a bug.

Answer (score 0):

Same with me, however I'm adept rank 3, I have 60 points invested and I still don't have biotic jimp/evade. Irritating since I'm using an asari sword and the charge skill. I'm going for a biotic duelest build and outside of looking cool. The biotic evade let's me teleport through environmental obstacles, so it's more essential than just cosmetic.